# Filling array of pointers by function c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

Hello I have made class `gabka` and a function `f1` to which I would like to pass an array of pointers to fill this array with `gabka` objects but I get weird error. How to correct it?

error:

```
cannot convert from gabka to int
```

the code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int n = 4;
class gabka {
public:
    float woda;

    gabka(){
        woda = 0;
    }

void f1(gabka t[n]){
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            t[i] = new gabka();
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    gabka** t = new gabka*[n];

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: I bet that you were also told what line of your code causes that error.  ;)

Comment: Whatever C++ book you are learning with, throw it way, it’s complete and utter crap, and it’s teaching you horrible C++. [Get a proper C++ book.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1968)

Answer (score 1):

Your `f1` function takes an array of `gabka` objects, and you are trying to assign a `gabka*` to each one of them. You need to decide what you want to pass to `f1`. For example,

```
void f1(gabka t[n]){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        t[i] = gabka(); // assign default constructed gabkas
    }
}
```

or

```
void f1(gabka* t[n]){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        t[i] = new gabka();
    }
}
```

In the latter case, bear in mind you have to call `delete` on all the elements of `t`.

It isn't clear what you are intending to do with your code, but, as a general rule, in C++ you should avoid raw pointers and manual dynamic allocation. Prefer standard library containers over dynamically allocates arrays or arrays of dynamically allocated objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
t[i] = new gabka();
```

`t` is an array of `gabka`, not an array of `gabka*`.

Either change the declaration of `t` to be an array of `gabka*`, or fill it with `gabka` instances.